# How to optimize for multiple columns search for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-indexes

I have a table in PostgreSQL, it has 20 columns, which are mostly of an enum type. And this table has millions of rows.

I'd like to support and speed up for queries searching for rows with multiple fields, for instance: `col2=value1&col3=value2&col5=value3 page=1`

I can't use PostgreSQL's compound index,
because it only works with a fixed order of the columns. For instance,  If I build an index on `(col2,col3,col5)`, then it can't be used for queries searching for `col1=value1&col2=value2`

And I'd like also to support queries like:

`col1=value1&col2=(value3 or value4) orderby=col3 page=1`

What would be a solution to this problem? And if I don't need full-text search on any of these columns (since they are all enum types), could the solution be lightweight?

Comment: How many *distinct*  combinations of col1...col20 do there exist?

Comment: I would say potentially hundreds of distinct combinations of any columns

Comment: You could collect them into a separate table,  addressed by a single (surrogate) key.

Answer (score 5):

If you want an `OR` in your search condition, that's pretty mush [“game over” for performance](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/avoid-or-for-better-performance/) (I'm exaggerating a little for effect).

But if you have only `AND`s and equality conditions, I want to call your attention to [Bloom filters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/bloom.html).

You just have to

```
CREATE EXTENSION bloom;
```

and then create an index `USING bloom` on all columns together.

Unlike other indexes, this single index can speed up queries with all possible combinations of columns in the `WHERE` condition. The index is just a filter that will pass some false positives, so there always has to be a recheck of the condition, but it will significantly speed up the query.